# What technology/framework should i use for an ipad web app?

Tags: ipad, drupal, mobile-website, jquery-mobile

I want to build a web based app targeting ipad. Users will be browsing an interactive menu and submitting orders to the kitchen. It would be nice to tie into an existing pos system but that may not always be an option.

The app needs to be highly responsive and perform like native. Cms would be nice because content changes often.

So what sort of frameworks should i be looking at? Im considering drupal with jquery mobile but i havent found too much info on that combo. Im still open and looking for an expert opinion.

Comment: HTML 5 for one, as you can have canvas for graphics, video inline, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The topic has been covered at the latest drupal conference in Chicago.

Here are the videos:

http://www.archive.org/details/drupalconchi_day2_drupal_on_the_go_with_jquery_mobile

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `jQuery mobile` on the frontend, plus a backend web framework with a templating system.  Any of these should suit your needs:

- Django/Python (heavy)
- Flask/Python (light)
- Rails/Ruby (heavy)
- Sinatra/Ruby (light)
- Symfony/PHP (heavy)
- PHP (light)